# How does APScheduler save the jobs in the database? (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, apscheduler

I am trying to figure out how looks the schema of a sqlite database after I save some jobs using Advanced Python Scheduler. I need it because I want to show the job in a UI. I tried to write a simple script which saves a job :

```
from pytz import utc

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

jobstores = {

    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///test.db')
}
executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}
job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 3
}
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())



scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_executor('processpool')
scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

try:
    scheduler.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```

But the command ".fullschema" in the terminal shows me that are no table and no data in the test.db. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two schedulers but only starting the one with default configuration.